# How to dequeue / deregister parent theme style

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style, parent-theme

I'm making a child theme, and I'd like to remove the Google font style that it calls for in 'fonts-style'

```
function nada_theme_styles() { 
    wp_register_style( 'fonts-style', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,700', array(), null, null );
  wp_register_style( 'nada-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

  wp_enqueue_style( 'fonts-style' );    
  wp_enqueue_style( 'nada-style' );    
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nada_theme_styles');
```

I currently have this:

```
function remove_nada_theme_font_style() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'fonts-style' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'fonts-style' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_nada_theme_font_style' );
```

I've tried that as well as adding my action to wp_print_scripts and styles, and changing the priority.

I've referenced similar threads here, and I'm not sure what I'm missing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Adding a priority of `11` or any bigger number should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple:

```
function remove_nada_theme_font_style() {
    remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nada_theme_styles' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_nada_theme_font_style' );
```

Since the child theme is loaded before the parent theme, you can't simply remove the action. because the add_action calls in the parent theme will simply overwrite your requests. You have to wrap it into the after_setup_theme hook. This hook will fire after the child and parent theme is loaded. So all removing filters and actions from the parent theme should go there.

Source: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-modify-the-parent-theme-behavior-within-the-child-theme--wp-31006

**edit**

This will remove the whole styles and not  just the font scripts.

If you just want to deregister the font:

```
function remove_nada_theme_font_style() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'fonts-style' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'fonts-style' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_nada_theme_font_style' );
```

Comment: but that will remove both css files when they only want one removed.

Comment: Good point... I will edit it accordingly

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about after_setup_theme...

Though it's still not working, the font is still there. Not sure what else I'm missing.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it!

 Just deregistering the font didn't seem to work, but I was able to use your first solution to remove the whole action, and then registered my own stylesheet in another function where I also registered my own google fonts.

 Thank you!

Comment: have you tried adding a higher priority number, as @Pieter Goosen suggested?